# Render hyperlink in pandas df in jupyterlab

Tags: pandas, formatting, amazon-sagemaker

I am trying to render a url inside a pandas dataframe output.  I followed along with some of the other examples out there, here is my implementation:

```
def create_url(product_name):
    search = 'http://www.example.com/search'
    url = 'http://www.example.com/search/'+product_name
    return url

def make_clickable(url):
    return '<a target="_blank" href="{}">{}</a>'.format(url, url)

...

df['url'] = df['product_name'].apply(format_url)
df.style.format({'url': make_clickable})
```

This produces a correctly formatted raw text hyperlink, however its not clickable within the output.

I should add that I'm doing this in an AWS sagemaker jupyterlab notebook which potentially disables hyperlinking in the output.  Not sure how I would check that though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this doesn't work, I'm guessing it's an AWS thing

1. `IPython.display.HTML`
2. `pandas.DataFrame.to_html` with `escape=False`
3. `pandas.set_option('display.max_colwidth', 2000)` Must be a large number to accommodate length of link tag.  I'll say that I think this is broken.  It shouldn't be necessary to set `'display.max_colwidth'` in order to make sure `to_html` outputs properly.  But it is :-/

---

```
from IPython import display

pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', 2000)

display.HTML(df.assign(url=[*map(make_clickable, df.url)]).to_html(escape=False))
```

[image]

Comment: Could you add some detail about what this is doing and why it works?

Comment: I mostly have already in the 3 bullet points at the top of my post.  But there is one thing I had planned on saying that I'll add.